# Select from different join tables

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm building a generic property system, where different entities may have properties (represented as 'PropertyEntity') assigned. Such a property entity has a key, a value and knows the id of the entity to which it is attached. Consider a 'UserEntity' in which a mapping for its properties would look like this:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
@JoinTable(name = "UserProperties",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "parentId"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id"))
private Map<String, PropertyEntity> properties;
```

There may also be more entities with properties, that each have their own join table.

I'm now wondering what would be the most efficient way to query for a User (or different entity that also has properties) with certain properties. Like 'Give me all Users where property A has value B and property X has value Y'.

Remember that the querying code must be generic in a way that it does not know whether a User or some other entity which has a property join table should be retrieved. The type to search for may be given as a Class object.

I'm currently running the naive approach in which the PropertyEntity also knows the name of the type to which it belongs. I then query the properties by their key and parent type and post process the result by manually finding the respective parent entities.

```
SELECT p FROM PropertyEntity p WHERE p.propertyKey in(?1) AND p.parentType = ?2
```

Where parameter 1 is a set of keys and parameter 2 the name of the parent type like 'com.domain.UserEntity'. This approach is obviously bad because it totally subverts the use of the extra join tables per entity and needs post filtering of the results by their values.

Comment: Eclipselink hat similar concept (dynamic entity) but this is non portable extension. Similar in terms goal to we want, implementation is different

Comment: you re trying to mean : `SELECT u FROM Users u WHERE u.properties.propertyKey in (?1) AND u.properties.parentType = ?2`

Comment: Probably yes. But `u.properties` is a Map (see snippet above) so the query can't be expressed this way. Additionally it misses the part to filter for certain property values and the second parameter would now be superfluous because we directly select from the target entity